# getting null pointer exception when trying to read from a cell in excel using webdriver

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet =wb.getSheet("TestData");
           Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
           Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
           String x = "";
     x =cell.getStringCellValue();
     System.out.println(x);
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException` at  Row row = sheet.getRow(1);

Comment: What Excel cell is the content in?  A1? B2? Please note that in Apache POI, rows and columns are 0-based, unlike the Excel GUI.

Comment: You're not using webdriver to read Excel, you are using Apache-POI.

Comment: @rgettman  
I have content in B2, so (1,1) should work, but still getting nullpointer

Comment: Does the `Sheeet` "TestData" exist?